# SSRS Report Viewer only works when Fiddler2 is running

Tags: wpf, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reportviewer, fiddler

I have a WPF application using a WinForms Report Viewer control.
The report control loads reports from SSRS 2008.
All was working fine until we moved to a new server.

All users can connect and authenticate to `http://SERVERNAME/reports` and run reports with no issues.
Certain users can run the reports from the WPF app but other users get the message:

> “The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized”.

I figured I would install Fiddler2 and see what traffic was being passed around.
Unfortunately (or fortunately), the reports load correctly in the Report Viewer control when Fiddler2 is running.

Why?

Though this is a "temporary workaround"; it is definitely not ideal.
And according to Fiddler... it works. The traffic appears to be valid I have nothing to fix.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended up being a bad configuration of a Barracuda Networks web filter proxy running on the network. The proxy was getting in the way of the Report Viewer control authenticating.  Why it still worked in IE or why it worked when Fiddler was running is still very strange to me but at least I now know what solves the problem.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your app was using a different proxy than IE/Fiddler except when Fiddler was running. You could verify with NetMon.